# How to replace the first occurrence of character 'e' in a string with 's' in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

like in my table-column first_name consists of values

first_name:

```
leena,
stev,
neene,
ajay,
vine.
```

and my question is that i only want to replace the first occurrence of character 'e' with 's' and the other occurrence of 'e' must remains the same that is it would not be replaced by 's'. And i need the output like below.

```
lsena,
stsv,
nsene,
ajay,
vins.
```

Answer (score 25):

Try this:

```
select regexp_replace(first_name,'e','s',1,1) 
from your_table
```

The regexp_replace function is explained here:
http://www.java2s.com/Book/Oracle/String_Functions/REGEXP_REPLACE_function.htm

Comment: You are correct, but I am unable to upvote you as you've completely failed to explain _why_ and _how_ this answers the question.

Comment: Added a link to the documentation. Did not know that I needed to explain why this works and not sure what to answer to _how_ it works. This is the SQL the OP was looking for, he can lookup the details of the function.

Comment: The documentation is here:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions149.htm, it works because of the fifth parameter, which is the occurrence of the matched string that needs to be replaced. As this is greater than 0 `regexp_replace()` replaces the nth, in this case first, occurrence of the pattern `'e'`. The fourth parameter is required when the fifth is used, 1 is the default and is the start position where the search should begin.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant, not so elegant as `regexp_replace`, but works too:

```
with example_data as (
  select 'leena' field0 from dual union all
  select 'stev'  field0 from dual union all
  select 'neene' field0 from dual union all
  select 'ajay'  field0 from dual union all
  select 'vine'  field0 from dual 
)
select
  field0,
  decode( instr(field0,'e'),
          0, field0, 
          substr(field0,1,instr(field0,'e')-1) || 's' || substr(field0,instr(field0,'e')+1)) 
from 
  example_data
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/12087)

Just for illustration.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mostly we can use 'regexp_replace' to replace particular character from a particular occurrence.
```

One of the simplest solution :

```
  SELECT REPLACE(
                 SUBSTR(COLUMN_NAME, 1,
                        instr(COLUMN_NAME,'e',1)),
                 'e', 's')
         || SUBSTR(COLUMN_NAME,
                   INSTR(COLUMN_NAME,'e',1)+1,
                   LENGTH(COLUMN_NAME))
  FROM TABLE_NAME
```